# Dynamic property as key VS List of objects in Javascript - which one will be more efficient

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I need a data structure something like HashMap(in JAVA)  where I want map status of user using user id as a key . So I can easily create a map **dynamically** like this:-

```
var mapOfIdVsStatus = {
  123: "true", 
  456: 'false'
}
alert(JSON.stringify(mapOfIdVsStatus));
```

In my scenario, new  **user id**  and **status** will be added/updated very frequently that is

```
Object.keys(mapOfIdVsStatus).length;
```

will increase. But this will help to search **status** of a user in a faster way.

I can do this in an alternative way like this:

```
var user1={
    id:123,
    status: true
}
var user2={
    id:456,
    status: false
}

var listOfUser = [];
listOfUser.push(user1);
listOfUser.push(user2);

alert(JSON.stringify(listOfUser));
```

I can also search **status** in the list for a user but need extra effort like *looping*..etc

Considering a lots of **Add**, **Search** and **Memory Optimization**  which one will be my best choice?

**Behaviors would be like:**

- Are keys usually unknown until run time? -**YES**
- Do you need to look them up dynamically? - **YES**
- Do all values have the same type? -**YES**
- Can they be used interchangeably?- **NO**
- Do you need keys that aren't strings? - Always String
- Are key-value pairs often added or removed?- Always added, No removal
- Do you have an arbitrary (easily changing) amount of key-value pairs?- **YES**
- Is the collection iterated? - I want to avoid iteration for faster
  access.

Comment: *"Do you need keys that aren't strings? - Always String"* And yet, your examples are using numbers (which are converted to strings in your example, because you're using them as object properties, but...).

Comment: It is just for example. Original user id is a string representaion of BSON object like : 5349b4ddd2781d08c09890f3

Answer (score 2):

The object, hands-down. Property lookup will be, at *worst*, a kind of hashmap-style lookup rather than a linear search.

If you do this, it's best to create the object without a prototype:

```
var mapOfIdVsStatus = Object.create(null);
```

...so it doesn't inherit properties from `Object.prototype`.

---

On ES2015-compliant JavaScript engines, you might also look at [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). `Map` is specifically designed to be a simple key/value map, and so is unencumbered by any object-ness. On Chrome and Firefox, at least in my simple test, it [performs as well or better than object lookup with string keys](https://jsperf.com/map-vs-object-lookup-time) (this is Chrome; Firefox seems to be similar):

[image]

...but [object lookup easily outpaces `Map` with number keys](https://jsperf.com/map-vs-object-when-keys-are-numbers) (this is also Chrome, on Firefox it was only twice as fast, not just under three times as fast):

[image]

**But**, those tests only test querying values once they've been added, not the tumult of adding new ones. (The updates you're talking about wouldn't matter, as you're changing the properties on the stored objects, not the thing actually stored, if I'm reading right.)

One really key thing is that if you need to *remove* entries, with an object you're better off setting the property's value to `null` or `undefined` rather than using `delete`. Using `delete` on an object can really, really slow down subsequent operations on it.

Comment: FYI: all keys are Strings and no delete operation will be done. Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The best choice is an ES6 [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). MDN gives some hints when to use it instead of a plain object:

> If you're still not sure which one to use, ask yourself the following questions:
>
> - Are keys usually unknown until run time? Do you need to look them up dynamically?
> - Do all values have the same type? Can they be used interchangeably?
> - Do you need keys that aren't strings?
> - Are key-value pairs often added or removed?
> - Do you have an arbitrary (easily changing) amount of key-value pairs?
> - Is the collection iterated?
>
> If you answered 'yes' to any of those questions, that is a sign that you might want to use a `Map`.

Comment: *"If you answer 'yes' to any of those questions..."*: so yes, `Map` is the way to go.